# error detection of sentences

Tags: discussion

I have one book, high school English, without answers. I'm not able to confirm completely by myself.

Can I put them here to check the answer? And I'll adhere my answer and comprehension to that.

If allowed and welcome, how many sentences in one post is appropriate?

of course welcome to rewrite the sentence or point out/edit my mistakes in post either.

For example:

Error Detection

[Without][A] green plants, the sun's energy [could not be used][B] on the earth, and [all other][C] organisms [live][D] on the earth would die. Seems true...

Comment: This kind of question is probably more appropriate for [ELL.se] unless you ask about specific grammatical structures, or have a general conceptual question about what you are learning.

Comment: I don't think ELL would want the kind of question OP seems to be suggesting with that example, either. Assuming it would be posed as something along the lines of "Which of these four elements goes in which of these four positions?", I think it would just be "homework looking for quick answers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posts should be limited to one question per post.  Multiple examples of a single problem may be given in a post.  But separate questions belong in separate posts.

Answer (score 7):

No. That sort of question is not appropriate for the main site. We are not set up to proof read documents or sentences.

While Stack Exchange is for asking specific questions, the questions should not be so specific that they only help you and only once. Questions should be broad enough that many people will find them usefull and narrow enough that the answers are not pages in length.

Comment: +1 for *questions should not be so specific that they only help you **and only once**.* That's precisely what OP's example typifies to me.